# Xpath was perfectly working yesterday, but today it is not working

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Xpath was working fine yesterday for a button that I wanted to click. But it is not working today. When trying to run the scripts, NoSuchElementException is coming there. Below I have added code and error.

**HTML Code:**

Source code for the 'Add Customer' button

```
<section class="content-header">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="col-xs-6 text-right">

<a class="btn btn-danger hidden checkdelbtn" data-content="Are you sure to continue?" data-title="Confirm" data-cancel="Cancel" data-confirm="Delete" data-form="userform" href="">

<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='http://lab-1.sketchdemos.com/musicshop/stores/musicshop/admin/add-customer.html'" value="Add Customer"/>

</div>
</div>
</section>
```

**Tried Code:**

```
//Clicking on 'Add Customer' button

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='userform']/section[1]/div/div[2]/input")).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

**Error:**

After executing above code, getting this error.

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='userform']/section[1]/div/div[2]/input"}
>
> Command duration or timeout: 32 milliseconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', `enter code here`time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
>   System info: host: 'SKETCH_QA-02', ip: '10.70.1.32', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_20'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: That's because your xpath is terrible. You should learn more about it before asking such questions here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this below `code` using `xpath locator`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Add Customer']")).click();
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `value` attribute of `<input>` tag.

**Note:-** Instead of using `absolute xpath`, use `relative xpath`.

> OR

Try this below `code` using `cssSelector`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Add Customer']")).click();
```

Comment: Hi Jainish,   thanks for your answer. I have already solved this problem by adding driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); before the code. Now it is working fine :)

Comment: Please `accept` this answer so it will help for other users as well :) and you didn't understand my point, you have entered absolute xpath, which is not good practice. because once your html will modified you will get an error like `element not found` so it's better for you to use relative xpath.